# Facing issue in retrieving contents from blob field

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I am working on an application based on Spring and Hibernate. I am facing some issue in retrieving contents from blob field (MySql Database). I have two scenarios:

**1. Scenario** Direct uploading document in the database table which is mapped to entity class. I am using the below code for this purpose:

//Code from controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(@ModelAttribute("baseTemplate") BaseTemplateEntity baseTemplate,
                       @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws SerialException, SQLException {

        String partName = baseTemplate.getPartName();
        String asil = baseTemplate.getAsil();
        try {
            Blob blob = new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(IOUtils.toByteArray(file.getInputStream()));
            baseTemplate.setFileName(file.getOriginalFilename());
            baseTemplate.setContent(blob);
            baseTemplate.setContentType(file.getContentType());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            baseTemplateManager.save(baseTemplate);
            logger.info("Document is saved successfully");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "redirect:/baseTemplates";
    }
```

Code from dao

```
 @Override
        public void save(BaseTemplateEntity template)  {
            this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(template); 
        }
```

With the help of above code I am able to upload the .xls document in the database.

**2. Scenario** I am uploading document in the database table which is not mapped to any entity class. that means i am creating database table dynamically.

//Code from controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/viewItemDocument/*/saveItemSafetyPlanTemplate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveItemSaeftyPlanDocument(@ModelAttribute("itemTemplate") ItemSafetyDocumentEntity itemTemplate,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws SerialException, SQLException {

        String partName = itemTemplate.getPartName();
        String asil = itemTemplate.getAsil();
        String itemName = itemTemplate.getItem();
        try {
            Blob blob = new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(IOUtils.toByteArray(file.getInputStream()));
            itemTemplate.setFileName(file.getOriginalFilename());
            itemTemplate.setContent(blob);
            itemTemplate.setContentType(file.getContentType());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            //Saving the edited/new document
            itemSafetyDocumentManager.saveItemEditedDocument(itemTemplate);
            logger.info("Document is saved successfully");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String tableName = itemName.toString().replace(" ", "")+"SafetyPlan";
        return "redirect:/viewItemDocument/"+tableName+"/"+itemName+"";
    }
```

//Code from dao

```
@Override
    public void saveItemEditedDocument(ItemSafetyDocumentEntity template)  {

        String tableName = template.getItem().toString().replace(" ", "")+"SafetyPlan";

        String createTable = "create table IF NOT EXISTS "+tableName;
        String query2 = createTable +"(ID int(11) primary key NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,Item varchar(255),Asil varchar(20),PartName varchar(255),Template longblob NOT NULL, ContentType varchar(255), FileName varchar(255), CreatedOn DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)"; 
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(query2).executeUpdate();

        String insert = "INSERT INTO "+tableName+"(Item, Asil, PartName, Template, ContentType, FileName) VALUES (:value1, :value2, :value3, :value4, :value5, :value6)";
         Query query1 = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(insert);
         query1.setParameter("value1", template.getItem());
         query1.setParameter("value2", template.getAsil());
         query1.setParameter("value3", template.getPartName());
         query1.setParameter("value4", template.getContent());
         query1.setParameter("value5", template.getContentType());
         query1.setParameter("value6", template.getFileName());
         query1.executeUpdate();
    }
```

With the help of above code I am able to upload the .xls document.
I have uploaded the same .xls document from both the methods. I opened MySql workbench and when I right click on the database blob field (select open value in text editor option) in both tables and compare the binary tab: the contents were different and data length in bytes were also different. I do not why and I want to know the reason.

Also when i tried to download the document from scenario 1, I am able to download successfully. But when I am using same downloading code for scenario 2, I am not able to download. Please help me..

//Download method from controller

```
@RequestMapping("/downloadDocument/{documentId}")
    public String download(@PathVariable("documentId") Integer documentId, HttpServletResponse response) {

        BaseTemplateEntity doc = baseTemplateManager.getById(documentId);
        try {
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"" +doc.getFileName()+ "\"");
            OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            response.setContentType(doc.getContentType());
            IOUtils.copy(doc.getContent().getBinaryStream(), out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Why on earth the complex hack... Just add a field of type `byte[]` to your entity add `@Lob` and let hibernate do the conversion...

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your reply. I will definitely explore this one. As I am new in spring and hibernate so i followed the available example. But how can I declare this type byte [ ] when i am creating table on the fly in scenario 2

Comment: Why are you using a `SessionFactory` or ORM in that situation then? That seems just horridly wrong. You use ORM and next bypass it as fast as you can, then just use plain JDBC instead of that contraption. Your first sample will correctly insert the blob, the second will serialize the object and store that. You would need to figure out how to write a BLOB for your underlying technology.

Comment: @M.Deinum Ok Thank you!! that is the reason when i download the document in the second scenario the contents in the .xls were like : java.sql.Blob%org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.WrappedBlobjava.io.Serializablexrjava.lang.reflect.Proxyá'Ú .

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks a lot !! You saved my night..